# Overflow? Is it not an Exchange?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions

For example when a question is closed as `Off Topic` it says:

[image: overflow???]

Shouldn't it say "Stack **Exchange** family of websites"?

Example Question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114356/155556

Comment: Looks like historical remnant, even Jeff wrote "Stack Overflow “family” of websites" in [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/migrate-questions-between-websites/) about two years ago - guess it was before Stack Exchange became so large. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, but that blog post was previous to the creation of the Stack Exchange ^_^ It should be updated

Comment: Sure, I never doubted it should be changed (+1 is obvious) just thought out aloud why it's like that. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes indeed, this has been corrected and it'll take effect immediately.