# Customize "Invite Fellow Experts" message in private beta?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, beta-phase, private-beta, invitation

Since you can now invite colleagues to [join you in a site's private beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107021/166017) (which I think is great), I wanted to make a request to make this feature a little better. I just used it to invite someone to the Movies Stack Exchange private beta, but I was really surprised that there was no option to customize - or even view - the invite message before it was sent.

I think it would be useful to have the ability to customize or add on a personal message to the invitation. For example, the person I was sending the invite to is  <strike>obsessed with</strike> knowledgeable about James Bond movies, so I specifically wanted to tell her that this would be a great place to share that expertise.

Since the reason behind that feature is to invite people you *know* are experts (and probably have some sort of relationship with), it makes sense to me to allow a personal message that might be more convincing than a form letter.

Is customizing the invite message a possibility? Even if if was just a pop-up box that adds on a personal message to the form letter part of the invite (i.e., I don't necessarily need to be able to change Stack Exchange's pre-written part), it would be useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Excellent idea - I have added a custom message section to the invite which will be deployed on the next build.

Comment: Damn, the dev team is responding quickly to our problems today!  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114370/1288

Comment: Code must be compiling obviously. No way they have this much time on their hands.

Comment: Right on, Geoff Dalgas! :D

Comment: @GeoffDalgas - It would be great if we could contact Stack Exchange members from other SE sites without knowing their email address. If we could type '@ User' into the "email a private beta invite to:" box and it would appear in their inbox feed in the upper right corner next time they visit any SE site.  - If that wouldn't be unambiguous for some reason (duplicate names across the websites) then perhaps the URL to the User Profile from any site. Thanks for considering my suggestion.